# How to run PostgreSQL setups independently of package based installations?

Tags: linux, postgresql, installation

I need to be able to run PostgreSQL databases outside the standard installation directories, ie run the existing `postgres` or `pg_ctl` process pointing to the alternative ports, configuration and data directories and get it running, with permissions etc working okay.

I don't want it to depend on the existing package based installation setup's structures in `/etc/postgresql` and `/var/run/postgresql` and the `postgres` user, but use their executables if possible.

I will not be using `initdb` much. The data will be unzipped from other installations. The only thing required is database compatibility with the existing package based installations, which I may be able to install if they are absent. Using executables of my own will be the last resort, due to the possibility of unexpected local dependencies.

The specific needs:

1. What data and configurations should be copied, ie the files and
   directories should be copied from `/etc/postgresql/xxx` and
   `/var/run/postgresql` and those relating to access rights
2. What executables are required, whether they can be extracted from
   existing packages ie rpm/deb directly or after they have been
   installations to their locations.

My preference will be to use the executables of the existing package based installations or install them if possible in case of dependencies which are not covered in my executables, with my executables as the second option.

Comment: You want a `schrink-wrapped boxed set`, independent of package-systems ? Will be hard. Best is imho to compile from source, (eg into /opt, since /usr/local has been squatted) . You still need some _manual_ fixes, for PATH and ldconfig, and /etc/init.d. Plus maybe some library / .so dependancies (libxml2, gzip, readline, ...)

Comment: In general all a postgres server needs is a data directory and a user that owns it to launch `postgres -D /path/to/data`. However data directories are not portable between heterogeneous systems. The _database compatibility_ and _my files_ you mention are too vague to guess what's exactly the structure of the data to move around.

Comment: will the person who voted to close explain the reason

Comment: @DanielVérité Database compatibility refers to the situation where the installed version is different from mine, eg 8.2 vs 8.4 or 8.x vs 9.x. By 'my files' I mean 'my executables'

Comment: You can download zip archives from here: http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgbindownload unzip them, run `initdb` and then `pg_ctl` with the aproriate parameters.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Are the enterprisedb archives designed to run independently of existing package based installations, without conflicts?

Comment: @vfclists: I don't use Linux so I can't tell for sure, but that works perfectly fine under Windows. As the base software is the same thing, I don't see why it shouldn't work with Linux either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not really clear what your question is.  There isn't anything special you need to do.  You can just unzip your existing data directory somewhere and run something like

```
/usr/bin/postgres -D /some/where/data
```

The binaries don't have any compiled-in knowledge of where the data or configuration directory is.

Comment: How about pg_hba.conf, postgresql.conf etc? Can they be configured independently from those in the regular locations?

Comment: Yes, the configuration files are by default located in the data directory.

Comment: That's good. Because the package installation places configuration settings under /etc/postgresql rather than /var/run/postgresql I thought the same applied when run standalone